# What, if any, anchor attributes are supported on asp:HyperLink?

Tags: html, asp.net

An `asp:HyperLink` element will of course generate a standard anchor tag. The following, for instance, will generate a `class` attribute.

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="foo" NavigateUrl="..."></asp:HyperLink>
```

Generates:

```
<a class="foo" href="..."></a>
```

Oddly enough, the standard `class` attribute appears to do the same in less characters.

```
<asp:HyperLink class="foo" NavigateUrl="..."></asp:HyperLink>
```

Generates:

```
<a class="foo" href="..."></a>
```

This is all fine enough, but try to set an `id` and you'll see this isn't always the case (The `HyperLink` class defines its own `ID` which takes precedance here). You'll also notice there is no intellisense when using a standard anchor attribute.

So my question is, is this expected behavior (I can't find it documented anywhere)? Is it guaranteed that if I define, say, an `onclick` attribute or anything that isn't already defined on the `HyperLink` class that it will transfer over to the generated anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f(v=vs.140).aspx):

> "Any attribute you add to a control that does not map to a property of that control is passed through to the browser."

Also, you can add any client side HTML attributes to any ASP.NET web control via the [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.  This may be a safer approach if you're not sure which attributes map to control properties.

Personally I find the whole property/attribute mapping exercise unnecessarily confusing, which is why I prefer MVC.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, thanks. Agreed on MVC, I'm only maintaining this code.